# How to convert from strings of base m to base n

Tags: python, python-3.x

how to convert from a string in base m to base n. since there are no direct ways to convert from base m to base n, i have decided to first convert from base n to base 10. i came up with this code:

```
to_convert = [x for x in input().split()] #string elements
number = to_convert[0] #substrings
m = to_convert[1] #starting base
n = to_convert[2] #end base

val_b10 = {'0': 0, '1': 1, '2': 2, '3': 3, '4': 4, '5': 5, '6': 6, '7': 7, '8': 8, '9': 9,
'A': 10, 'B': 11, 'C': 12, 'D': 13, 'E': 14, 'F': 15, 'G': 16, 'H': 17, 'I': 18, 'J': 19, 'K': 20,
'L': 21, 'M': 22, 'N': 23, 'O': 24, 'P': 25, 'Q': 26, 'R': 27, 'S': 28, 'T': 29, 'U': 30, 'V': 31,
'W': 32, 'X': 33, 'Y': 34, 'Z': 35}

#invalid m or n
if 2 < int(m) < 36 or 2 < int(n) < 36:
    print('Invalid Input. 2 <= m,n <= 36')

#digits outside base m

#convert number to base 10
sum_b10 = 0
for i in range(len(number) - 1, -1, -1):
    for digit in number:
        sum_b10 += val_b10[digit] * (int(m)**i)
print(sum_b10)
```

however, sum_b10 is not quite the answer. also, how would you know the digits that don't belong to the base??

Comment: What inputs did you use and what outputs did you get? What did you expect?

Comment: for ZZ base 36, i get 2950, w/c is double the correct answer. for 10000000 base 2, i get 255 (128 is the correct answer)

Comment: And why don't you just use `int("ZZ", 36)`, see `help(int)`? Or is this just for learning, then forget my question ;)

Answer (score 2):

You have 3 problems in your code:

- you iterate twice on `number` (the 2 `for` loops)
- you consider the digits in the wrong order: least significant digit first, whereas the natural order is most significant first
- this test looks wrong: `if 2 < int(m) < 36 or 2 < int(n) < 36:` (what is the purpose here?)